# Putting a new function name in an internal macro

Tags: rust, macros

trying to write a really basic macro in Rust. I'm trying to turn a multi-line declaration (using nom) into a single line as it's replicated a huge amount. The following is the macro I'm trying to define:

```
macro_rules! tag_parser {
    ($name:ident, $tag:expr, $ret:expr) => {
        nom::named!(
            $name<&str, AnsiSequence>,
            nom::do_parse!(
                nom::tag!($tag) >>
                ($ret)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And here is an example invocation:

```
tag_parser!(cursor_restore, "u", AnsiSequence::CursorRestore);
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
error: no rules expected the token `cursor_restore`
  --> src/parsers.rs:95:13
   |
95 | tag_parser!(cursor_restore, "u", AnsiSequence::CursorRestore);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

Really, the issue is focused around the first parameter. For some reason it will not let me place it the way I have inside the macro. I'm not sure if this is due to me calling another macro (named!) or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is this the real code? The error message says "a_cursor_restore", the example says "cursor_restore".

Comment: Sorry, it is. I already had the parser declared, so when using the macro I temporarily added an 'a'. I removed it in the examples, but forgot it in the error. Other than that, everything is identical, so yes it's the real code. Good catch!

Comment: Stripped of it's body, the macro invocation works fine. What's the context of line 95? Are you inside another macro invocation?

Comment: Nope, no context. Where a standard function definition would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell why the macro expansion fails in the way it does. It does, however, get hung up on the full path to the nom-macro being called in the expansion. If you add `use nom::*;` to bring `do_parse` and `named` into scope beforehand and strip the two `nom::`-fragments (`nom::named!...` -> `named!...`) from the macro-body, it works.

Comment: How strange. I thought I even tried that already. Oh well, very weird. Thank you for the help!